What should I specify as the mate to do a rection force motion study on a crank on its gorund?
I have a crankshaft assembly where I am meant to create a graph of the reaction force of the crank on the ground. The motor is placed on this crank set to 1800 rpm. The crank is mated to the ground using a coincident mate for the circular face and the face of the ground and a concentric mate for the two cylindrical faces. The graph is not coming out how I expect it to or how it is supposed to. What should I be using as the "entities to measure" when creating the plot? Is there anything else I should be considering to fix this? I have included images of my part and graph as well as the graph I am supposed to be achieving.
Thanks!
goal graphMy part and graph
